# Bounds on the two first moments of the absolute value of a random variable?

Tags: probability

> **Question**. Let $X$ be a random variable with finite mean and possibily finite variance. Can we find bounds for the mean and variance of $|X|$?

In case of $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ we have

$$\begin{align}E(|X|) &= \sigma \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \,\, \exp\left(\frac{-\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) + \mu \mbox{erf}\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2\sigma^2}}\right)\\
V(|X|) &= \mu^2 + \sigma^2 - E(|X|)^2
\end{align}$$

But I do not know more general results.

Comment: No, because a random variable does not necessarily have a mean or a variance. In the most general setting of random variables, it is not possible to bound neither the mean nor the variance.